# django-cms==3.2.3 migration from Django 1.5.12 to 1.9.5 choices error

Tags: django, upgrade, django-cms, django-1.9

While working a migration of an older Django project I ran into this error after running:

```
python manage.py check

cms.UserSettings.language: (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.
```

Has anyone run into this issue? Unfortunately I have to wait until I am not on the corp network before I can ask the IRC channels.

Comment: You should migrate in stages, there have been *huge* changes from 1.5.x to 1.9.x

Comment: Can you post the relevant code of your model? This particular error seems to indicate that the tuple you are passing as the possible choices for the `language` field of your `UserSettings` model is not good. This could be a red herring, though, because as @Sayse mentions that's a *big* hop

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28304776/are-numerically-keyed-choices-no-longer-possible-in-django-1-7 : did you forget to add a comma for one-choice tuple?

Comment: I did actually incrementally upgrade versions of django and django-cms I believe I just missed something in-between.  I was thinking the same thing as far as the UserSettings model but the problem is this doesn't exist in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#cms-languages

It turns out I missed this important setting in my settings.py file:

```
CMS_LANGUAGES = {
    'default': {
       'fallbacks': ['en',],
        'redirect_on_fallback':True,
        'public': True,
        'hide_untranslated': False,
    }
}
```

Thanks to brianpck for a point in the right direction though.